# threading tkinter add label in frame during function execution

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I write a pipeline for a lab, so I know it is impossible to insert a "console" in a GUI, so I made it with a Frame and I put label on it.

But the problem is, I am a beginner in threading, and I don't know how to use it to put my label into my frame after a function execution in a loop.

So this is my code (python 3.x) :

```
########
# IMPORTS #
########

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import os
import glob
from datetime import date, time, datetime

#########
# FUNCTION #
#########

def OneFile(path1,DB,path2,seq,seq2,typ,path3):
    """
    This function is very long, take all the sequences of the input file and BLAST it to the Library DATABASE
    path : path to the library databse
    DB : library database name
    path2 : path of the file with the query sequences
    seq : name of the file with the query sequences append with a job ID
    seq2 : name of the file with the query sequence 
    Typ : Nucleotide or Proteine
    """
    from datetime import date, time, datetime
    import subprocess
    import platform
    import time
    OS = platform.system()
    if OS == 'Linux' or OS == 'Darwin':
        pathLibrary = path1+'/'
        pathSequence = path2+'/'
        pathFolder = path3+'/'
    if OS == 'Windows':
        pathLibrary = path1+'\\'
        pathSequence = path2+'\\'
    if typ not in [(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)]:
        showerror('Error : Missing Type !', "You do not choose your type\n(nucleotides or proteins)")
    else:
        library = DB
        if os.path.isfile(pathLibrary+library) != True:
            showerror('Error : Missing File !', "You must choose a Library Database file")
        else:
            if os.path.isfile(pathSequence+seq2) != True:
                showerror('Error : Missing File !', "You must choose your sequence file")
            else:
                if typ == (1,1):
                    typ = "blastn"
                if typ == (2,2):
                    typ = "blastp"
                if typ == (1,2):
                    typ = "blastx"
                if typ == (2,1):
                    typ = "tblastn"
                if OS == 'Linux' or OS == 'Darwin':
                    t0 = time.time()
                    query = str(seq2)
                    blast = str(seq)+'_Blast.txt'
                    seqs = str(seq)+'_seqs.txt'
                    subprocess.call(typ+" -query "+pathSequence+query+" -db "+pathLibrary+library+" -evalue 1e-10 -out "+pathFolder+blast, shell=True)
                    subprocess.call("grep '\(Sbjct\|>\)' "+pathFolder+blast+" > "+pathFolder+seqs, shell=True)
                    t1 = time.time()
                    print('Job finish in '+str(round(t1-t0,2))+' seconds')
                if OS == 'Windows':
                    t0 = time.time()
                    query = str(seq2)
                    blast = str(seq)+'_Blast.txt'
                    seqs = str(seq)+'_seqs.txt'
                    subprocess.call(typ+' -query '+pathSequence+query+' -db '+pathLibrary+library+' -evalue 1e-10 -out '+pathSequence+blast, shell=True)
                    print('Fichier n° '+str(1)+' '+str(seq2))
                    subprocess.Popen('findstr "Sbjct >" '+pathSequence+blast+' > '+pathSequence+seqs, shell=True)
                    t1 = time.time()
                    print('Job finish in '+str(round(t1-t0,2))+' seconds')

#######
# CLASS  #
#######

class GraphicalUserInterface():
    #principal application
    def __init__(self):
        #constructor
        self.fen = Tk()
        self.fen.title("Starch Enzyme Pipeline")

        #first label
        self.label1 = Label(self.fen, text="Folder with your set(s) : ")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
        #first button
        self.browse1 = Button(self.fen)
        self.browse1.config(text="Browse",command=self.folderPath)
        self.browse1.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky="W")

        #label to show the path
        self.varLabel1 = StringVar()
        self.pathLabel1 = Label(self.fen, textvariable=self.varLabel1, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.pathLabel1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky="EW")

        #second title
        self.label2 = Label(self.fen, text="Folder with your library database(s) ")
        self.label2.grid(row=2,column = 0, columnspan=2 , sticky="W")

        #second button
        self.browse2 = Button(self.fen)
        self.browse2.config(text="Browse",command=self.folderPath2)
        self.browse2.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky="W")

        #label to show the path for database
        self.varLabel2 = StringVar()
        self.pathLabel2 = Label(self.fen, textvariable=self.varLabel2, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.pathLabel2.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky = "EW")

        #Frame wrappe listBox and other
        self.frameListBoxAll = Frame(self.fen)
        self.frameListBoxAll.grid(row=6,columnspan=2)

        #list box label
        self.labListBox1 = Label(self.frameListBoxAll, text="Your sets :",padx=10)
        self.labListBox1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.labListBox2 = Label(self.frameListBoxAll, text="Your library database :",padx=10)
        self.labListBox2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        #frame with listbox1
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.frameListBoxAll, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1,column=0)

        #frame with listbox1
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.frameListBoxAll, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.frame2.grid(row=1,column=1)

        #scrollbar listbox1
        self.scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(self.frame1)
        self.scrollbar1.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="NS")
        self.scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(self.frame2)
        self.scrollbar2.grid(row=0,column=3, sticky="NS")
        self.scrollbar3 = Scrollbar(self.frame1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbar3.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky="WE")
        self.scrollbar4 = Scrollbar(self.frame2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbar4.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky="WE")

        #liste box
        self.listeBox1 = Listbox(self.frame1, selectmode=EXTENDED, exportselection=0, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar1.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar3.set)
        self.listeBox1.grid(row=0,column = 0)
        self.scrollbar1.config(command=self.listeBox1.yview)
        self.scrollbar3.config(command=self.listeBox1.xview)

        #liste box2
        self.listeBox2 = Listbox(self.frame2, selectmode=EXTENDED, exportselection=0, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar2.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar4.set)
        self.listeBox2.grid(row=0,column = 2)
        self.scrollbar2.config(command=self.listeBox2.yview)
        self.scrollbar4.config(command=self.listeBox2.xview)

        #radioboutton list box 1
        self.var = IntVar()
        for item in [1,2]:
            if item == 1:
                self.rb = Radiobutton(self.frameListBoxAll, text='Nucleotides',value=item,variable=self.var)
                self.rb.grid(row=2, column=0)
            if item == 2:
                self.rb = Radiobutton(self.frameListBoxAll, text='Proteins',value=item,variable=self.var)
                self.rb.grid(row=3, column=0)

        #radioboutton list box 2
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        for item in [1,2]:
            if item == 1:
                self.rb2 = Radiobutton(self.frameListBoxAll, text='Nucleotides',value=item,variable=self.var2)
                self.rb2.grid(row=2, column=1)
            if item == 2:
                self.rb2 = Radiobutton(self.frameListBoxAll, text='Proteins',value=item,variable=self.var2)
                self.rb2.grid(row=3, column=1)
        #variables
        self.path1 = str()
        self.path2 = str()
        self.path3 = str()
        #RUN Buttun
        self.runbutton = Button(self.fen, text="RUN",command=self.start_foo_thread).grid(row=7,column=0,columnspan=2)

        #FRAME CONSOLE
        self.console = Frame(self.fen)
        self.console.config(relief=SUNKEN, bg="black", height=200, width=400)
        self.console.grid(row=8, columnspan=10)
        self.console.grid_propagate(False) #to block the size of the frame

        #QUIT BUTTON
        self.quitButton = Button(self.fen)
        self.quitButton.config(text="QUIT", command=self.fen.destroy)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=100,column=0)

    def folderPath(self):
         path = askdirectory(title='Choose your set folder')
         self.varLabel1.set(path)
         self.listeBox1.delete(0, END)
         for filename in sorted(glob.glob(path+'/*')):
             if os.path.isfile(filename):
                 #stockage of path
                 self.path1 = os.path.split(filename)[0]
                 name = os.path.split(filename)[1]
                 self.listeBox1.insert(END, name)

    def folderPath2(self):
        path = askdirectory(title="Choose your library database folder")
        self.varLabel2.set(path)
        self.listeBox2.delete(0, END)
        for filename in sorted(glob.glob(path+'/*')):
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                #stockage of path
                self.path2 = os.path.split(filename)[0]
                name = os.path.split(filename)[1]
                self.listeBox2.insert(END, name)

    def run(self):
        self.fen.mainloop()

    def createJobName():
        job = str(datetime.now())
        job = job.replace(" ","-")
        return job

    def typeNP(self):
        liste = []
        #selection of query files
        valListBox1 = [self.listeBox1.get(idx) for idx in self.listeBox1.curselection()]
        #selection of database file
        valListBox2 = [self.listeBox2.get(idx) for idx in self.listeBox2.curselection()]
        #selection of sequence type
        typ = (self.var.get(),self.var2.get())
        # loop
        for i in range(len(valListBox2)):
            job = GraphicalUserInterface.createJobName()
            path1 = self.path2
            path2 = self.path1
            DB = valListBox2[i]
            path3 = os.getcwd()+"/"+DB+job
            if os.path.isdir(DB+job) == True:
                showwarning('Warning', "The folder already exist \n or they are no folder name !\nChange or get the folder name")
            else:
                os.mkdir(DB+job)
            for filename in valListBox1:
                seq = filename+job
                seq2 = filename
                #stock data for OneFile function
                liste.append([path1,DB,path2,seq,seq2,typ,path3])
        return liste

    def start_foo_thread(self):
        liste = self.typeNP()
        for i in range(len(liste)):
            global foo_thread
            import threading
            print('Fichier n°'+str(i+1)+' '+str(liste[i][4]))
            stringLabel = Label(self.console,text='Fichier n°'+str(i+1)+' '+str(liste[i][4]),bg='black', fg='white')
            stringLabel.grid(row=i,sticky="W")
            foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=OneFile(liste[i][0],liste[i][1],liste[i][2],liste[i][3],liste[i][4],liste[i][5],liste[i][6]))
            foo_thread.daemon = True
            foo_thread.start()



#########
# AUTORUN #
#########

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GraphicalUserInterface()
    app.run()
```

The problem is when the loop began in:

```
    def start_foo_thread(self):
        liste = self.typeNP()
        for i in range(len(liste)):
```

With the print function, I see the function run, but the label does not go in the frame when the iteration finishes. When the loops are completed, I see my label in the frame.
What is the correct code to have my label in my frame at the same time my function runs in my loop?

Comment: Much to read. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You cannot access tkinter widgets from any thread other than the thread that created them. Do some more research by searching for `[tkinter] threading` on this site. It is a complex subject, which perhaps makes your question too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sometimes have to manually update the widget.  You have posted too much code to wade through, so this simple example should show the problem.  Run as is, the labels don't show up until the function returns.  Run with update_idletasks() uncommented does what I think you want.  Also note that the program stops until the call to subprocess returns.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class GraphicalUserInterface():
    def __init__(self):
        #constructor
        self.fen = tk.Tk()
        self.fen.title("Starch Enzyme Pipeline")
        self.console=tk.Frame(self.fen)
        self.console.grid()
        self.liste=["one", "two", "three"]
        tk.Button(self.fen, text="Exit", command=self.fen.quit).grid(row=1)
        self.start_foo_thread()
        self.fen.mainloop()

    def start_foo_thread(self):
        for ctr in range(len(self.liste)):
            lit='Fichier n %s' % (ctr)
            print(lit)
            stringLabel = tk.Label(self.console, text=lit,
                                   bg='black', fg='white')
            stringLabel.grid(row=ctr,sticky="W")
            ##self.console.update_idletasks()
        print("Waiting 2 seconds")
        self.fen.after(2000)  ## wait 2 seconds to show effect
        print("Return from function")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GraphicalUserInterface()
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank you very much for your help!
There I missed the line of code:
`self.console.update_idletasks()`

after I had what I wanted :)

This is my first real post
I'm studying bioinformatics and I am French
Thank you to those who have corrected the message
Thank you for those who have read and responded

thank you a lot

Yoan